# ionic v2 slower than v1 on android

Tags: android, performance, ionic-framework, ionic2

When starting an ionic v2 tabs App, it takes nearly 12 seconds until I see the tabs-screen. In comparison, the v1 app only needs around 3 seconds. 
In V1, I see the start up screen and it directly turns into the tabs screen
In V2, I see the start up screen (for the same time), it than turns into a white screen for like 7 seconds before it turns into the tabs screen.

This is ALL I did in V1

```
ionic start test_v1 tabs
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

After the app started, I closed it; the time mentioned above is the app loading time, when the app is already on my smartphone

This is ALL I did in V2

```
ionic start testapp tabs --v2
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

After the app started, I closed it; the time mentioned above is the app loading time, when the app is already on my smartphone

ionic Version:  CLI v2.1.17
Your system information:

ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Not installed

I tried with a Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini Duos (that's where the boot times came from) and an S6 Edge Plus (which was more performant, but the time differences was still there). Both Android 6

Any ideas, what could be wrong?

Comment: Finally got it working by updating all packages and un- and reinstalling multiple times. Not the way I'd liked to solve this, but it helped. My App is now starting out within 6 seconds.